# Hibernate First Level Cache

Tags: hibernate

```
Session ses = factory.openSession();

Student s = (Student)ses.get(Student.class, new Integer(101));
System.out.println(s.getStudentId());

Hi

Person p = (Person)ses.get(Person.class, new Integer(101));

System.out.println(p.getPerson());
ses.close();
```

Q1: Whether we save same table object in the session cache or we can save two differnt table objects in the same session.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

It depends of the mapping. If Student inherits from Person and is mapped that way then the second session.get will return the same instance.